# MATCH Works in Some Cells, Not Others

Tags: google-sheets

### Background

I've been making a custom DnD character sheet in Google Sheets, and have come across a problem.

I've been trying to make two cells which have drop-down menus allowing someone to select a class and subclass. To avoid clutter, I've been trying to make it so that after a class is selected, the 'subclass' dropdown box only shows subclasses for the selected class.

Looking online, it seems the best way to do this is to make a proxy column where each cell corresponds to one of the options you want, then populate it with the selected class's subclasses based on the value of the 'class' cell (I found this approach in [this tutorial](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4667-google-sheets-dependent-drop-down-list.html)).

Unfortunately, the solution given in the tutorial is gross and doesn't scale. I might be adding new classes or subclasses in the future, and don't want to have to make a brand new formula every time I want a new class. While the formula provided can be easily extended to work for potentially infinite subclasses, adding a new class requires copying and pasting a bunch of code into what will eventually become longer and longer piece of spaghetti.

Despite this, I've found a formula that does scale for both! Examining the below screenshot, pay particular attention to P11 (the out-of-place block of text beneath the '3'):
[image: This is what the 'metadata' spreadsheet looks like currently.]
The formula in the highlighted cell is identical to the formula in P11, which you can see displays the expected results (the cell E3 in another tab has been set to 'Cleric'). Despite this, the other cell displays an *'An array value could not be found'* error. Some debugging reveals this to be a problem with the 'MATCH' statements in the formula (which also cause an error when placed individually into the same cell).

### The Problem

If the 'MATCH' statement were to work in this cell as it does in the other cell, I would have no worries. Hence, I'd like to know why I'm getting the error I'm getting, and how to fix it.

On the other hand, maybe there's a better way of solving this problem that I haven't even thought of which I'm better off using in the long term, in which case I'm open for hearing that too. If you notice the rows for 'Subclass Prefix' and 'Subclass Suffix', my next plan is to make all the subclasses automatically have a given suffix and prefix, so it'd be nice for my final approach to be friendly to this (brownie points if you can point me in the right way to accomplishing this).

### Supplementary Material

The following is the formula visible in the spreadsheet.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(REGEXREPLACE(ADDRESS(7, MATCH('Basic Character Details'!E3, D3:3, D7:7)+3, 4, False), "[\[\]]", ""), ":", REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(ADDRESS(7, MATCH('Basic Character Details'!E3, D3:3, D7:7)+3, 4, False), "[\[\]]", ""), "^..", "")), False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more robust and future-proof solution, I'd suggest laying your data out like this and using a QUERY() function to limit what goes into your subclass options:

```
COL A       COL B

Class       Subclass
---------------------------
Fighter     Champion
Fighter     Battle Master
Fighter     Eldritch Knight
etc.
```

For your first list that goes into the data validation (unique Classes) the query looks like this:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A, COUNT(A) GROUP BY A")
```

Then once someone has selected a class, the valid subclass list is returned like this:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT B, COUNT(B) WHERE A = '" &D1& "' GROUP BY B")
```

(Where D1 is the location of the currently selected class). Don't forget the single quotes or the query won't work.

You can see how adding the prefixes and suffixes to this data structure could allow you to accomplish the same thing with those as well.

FYI - The QUERY() function is unique to Google Sheets AFAIK.

Comment: You mentioned adding prefixes would be easy with this data structure - do I need to manually add the prefix to everything in column B? Because otherwise, it looks like I need to add it to every element of column A. Or is the idea I have a second table for this information?

Comment: I'd suggest a prefix column and a suffix column as well, so:

`Class       Subclass       Prefix       Suffix`

As your data structure. You can then pull prefix and suffix options in the same way as subclass options.

You can use AND in the 'WHERE' part of the query like 
`"WHERE A = '"&D1&"' AND B = '"&D2&"' `